# Is dispatcher in zend framework more or less a Dependency Injection module?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, dependency-injection

As you can see from this diagram (from 15 to 24) a dispatcher:
Click [here](http://www.kitpages.fr.s3.amazonaws.com/bundle/kitpagesFileSystem/kitpagesFile/public/18/18/sequence_globale.jpg) for a bigger image.
[image: Zend Framework calls]

The dispatch has the following steps:

> - instantiate a controller(15)
>
>   - preDispatch (to a helper)(17-18)
>   - preDispatch (interpret preDispatch data?)(19)
>   - action (execute for results based on preDispatch data?)(20)
>   - postDispatch (I do not understand this!?)(21)
>   - postDispatch (to a helper but why?)(22-23)
> - back to dispatcher(24)
>
>   ---
> - What functionality is it referred to when a dispatch, preDispatch, postdispatch is done?
> - What is a functionality of dispatcher in zend framework? Is it more or less a Dependency Injection module?

Comment: The image is broken, please add it again otherwise I'd say the question is not helpful.

Comment: @hakre Hello Hakre, The broken link is fixed :).

Answer (score 2):

Those dispatch methods are part of Zend_Controller's [plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) system.  You could think of them as hooks.

In your bootstrap, you can register plugins which get executed during one or more of those events.  For example, if you register a plugin in Bootstrap which contains a `routeShutdown` method, Zend Framework will execute that your plugin's routeShutdown method during routeShutdown.

Plugins can be told to run during #8-12, and #26-28.  Zend_Controller_Action also has pre/postDispatch methods (#17 and #22) you can use directly in your controller that will run unconditionally for every action in that controller.

One would register plugins for the different events based on where you want certain logic to take place.  For example, you could make a plugin to check if the user is visiting the site over https; and you would want this to run before any application logic takes place (controllers/actions), so it wouldn't make sense to check for https in postDispatch because the controller's action has already performed all of its logic and has rendered the output.  Instead you would want to use `routeShutdown` since at that point the module, controller, and action are known since routing has occurred.

In one of my apps, I have a plugin that displays how many queries were executed and roughly how long it took to generate the page from when index.php was called, so I have this plugin run last in `dispatchLoopShutdown` since the request is almost terminated.  From there I can get access to the HTML body that will be returned with the response, and manipulate it to include the profile information.

[Zend Controller Basics](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.basics.html) and [The Dispatcher](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.dispatcher.html) references should also help on top of the [plugins](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) reference above.

Hopefully that helped clear it up for you a bit.